# iOS 5.1 app crash on startup with Symbol not found: _NSFontAttributeName

Tags: ios, debugging, ios5, crash, nsattributedstring

I am getting below error while running app on iPad with iOS 5.1.1

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _NSFontAttributeName
  Referenced from: /var/mobile/Applications/9471D711-BCA7-4529-A584-9747C2E03DBC/egnyteMobileIOSUniversal.app/egnyteMobileIOSUniversal
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
 in /var/mobile/Applications/9471D711-BCA7-4529-A584-9747C2E03DBC/egnyteMobileIOSUniversal.app/egnyteMobileIOSUniversal
```

Where as in my code, i now where use NSFontAttributeName constant .As i am aware it is supported for iOS equal or above 6.0.Neither in my code i am using NSAttributedString Class.
Is that possible that some other method or UI controls is calling in this method internally?
Stack-trace doesnt give me any information on which code or method is getting this issue.
Is there any way by which i can debug trace symbols error properly ? 
My application supports min 5.0 iOS

Comment: Is your BaseSDK set to iOS5? Are you using third party libraries that may cause the trouble?

Comment: Please share some code which is creating problem.

Comment: Same issue, did some solution worked for u?

Comment: Yes , my selected answer solved issue.Change the Type for UIKit from Required to Weak and rebuild your application target. That should take care of the runtime errors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change the Type for UIKit from Required to Weak and rebuild your application target. That should take care of the runtime errors.

Comment: Thanks @er.vish The UIKit framework in iPhone OS 6.0 added the constant "NSFontAttributeName", and if you link it in as normal your application will assume those symbols exist on 5.1, where they don't.

Answer (score 3):

NSFontAttributeName can be used for text size calculating. If you can't find it in your < iOS 6 project by CMD+Shift+F, may be it used in external library.